# How can I call a Qtproject from matlab?

Tags: qt, matlab

I have a function in matlab that writes a file.txt which i use in my qt project.

So,

I have a Matlab file when I get a qt compiled executable to run using the unix(), but I'm getting an error.

the code:

```
unix('/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui');
```

the error:

```
/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui: symbol lookup error: /home/matt/Desktop
/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui: undefined symbol: _ZN9QListData7detach3Ev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as @grungetta is also pointing out, may be related to MATLAB local library path not seeing your Qt libraries, like `libQtMultimedia.so`, which should normally in a path visible in any shell session through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` var.

One way to work around this is explicitly setting the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from within a MATLAB running session (and then re-storing it if you need to continue). An example set of commands for your MATLAB script may be:

```
%*** save local (MATLAB's) LIBRARY PATH
libPathLocal = getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH');  

%*** set your global LIBRARY PATH 
PATH_LD_LIBRARY = '/usr/lib/' % or any string containing library files required 
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', PATH_LD_LIBRARY); 

%*** call binary through 'unix' or 'system'
system('/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui'); 

%*** restore session's MATLAB's library path
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', libPathLocal);
```

Comment: it works but my qt gets a segmentation fault in the qvtkwidget

Comment: glad it worked. I run into similar problems in running Python or calling binaries depended on custom or external libraries.

Comment: but now I have a little problem. I had a function to write new bmp files but whern i call matlab it doesn't work, it only works if i open the qt program into qt creator.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand completely. You have a MATLAB function to write .bmp or a function through Qt that is called by MATLAB? Is this related to Qt libraries? If yes, what is the error you get. Depending on the problem, perhaps a new post might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure in what way you would like to *call a Qt project*; however, the MATLAB [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) command might be helpful.  This command is used to execute an operating system command and return the result.

So if you are just looking to start an executible from MATLAB, this is probably what you want.

Also, [dos](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dos.html) and [unix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unix.html) are two related MATLAB commands that might be more appropriate depending on your situation.

Comment: I guess you're right, I'm trying to call an executable created by my qt project.

Comment: executing the unix command like this: `unix('/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui')` I got the error `/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libQtMultimedia.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN14QObjectPrivate15checkWindowRoleEv`

Comment: So, I'm assuming that 1) executing `/home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui` from the linux shell works, and 2) executing a simple command like `unix('ls')` from MATLAB works. This error might be related to the fact that MATLAB starts in a new shell and changes certain environment variables. You can check for differences in environment variables by executing `env` from the shell before starting MATLAB and comparing that to `unix('env')` executed from inside MATLAB.

Comment: Last time I ran into an issue like this with the `unix` command, the particular environment variable that had changed was LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The very quick and dirty way that I resolved the issue was to copy the contents of this variable before starting MATLAB (calling `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then just copying the output), and then using this value in a MATLAB script that called [setenv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setenv.html) to manually reset this environment variable.  I would then execute this script before I would attempt to run my external program with the `unix` command.

Comment: I couldn't complete that, can you give more details please?

Comment: When you say that you couldn't complete that, do you mean that the description I gave was unclear or that you tried this and you still got the same error.

Comment: I was not able to do what you told me.

Comment: The solution that I was referring to in my previous comments (regarding environment variables) is pretty much exactly what @gevang has explicitly implemented in code in his answer. Rather than me trying to clarify my comments and just providing duplicate information, I suggest just referring to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience working with Matlab but here are my 2 cents.

1. If /home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui works OK from command prompt then it seems that MatLab is not able to find the libQtCore.so (I am not exactly sure about how the library is named, but I am referring to QtCore library). In that case copy the Qt's Core library to one of the MatLab's search locations and try.
   If it gives you same error from the command prompt then it means that Qt's libraries are not in search path. May be you can add PATH_TO_QTLIBS in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
2. One other reason could be that you might have more than one versions of Qt on your system and the loader is trying to reference a different version when you try running the application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with library versions. The binary was compiled with a QT version different from the QT on system?
How many library versions are in system?
What output gives when executing "ldd /home/matt/Desktop/PlaneVolumeFinal/PlaneVolumeGui"?