# Matlab - Error using feval Unrecognized function or variable 'py.dict'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to call python from Matlab using its python interface.  I am first setting the env then calling a simple example but am getting an error:

```
pyenv('Version', ... 
  '../bin/python', ... 
  'ExecutionMode','OutOfProcess') 

pyrun("l = ['A','new','list']")  
l

Error using feval
Unrecognized function or variable 'py.dict'.
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? What version of Python is `../bin/python`?

Comment: This *might* be a dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37152895/7328782 — Does that solve your issue?